# How to disable CheckBox in Scene2D so it doesn't react to click

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Is there a way to disable a Scene2D CheckBox so it doesn't react to clicking?

Comment: Does this method works? setDisabled(boolean isDisabled)

Comment: Yes , thanks! Put it as the answer , I'll accept it!

Comment: It's ok, i'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as described in: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html#setDisabled-boolean-

checkbox.setDisabled(true);